# SCSS code-style for adding child overrides on hover

Tags: sass, coding-style, styles

I'm curious if anyone solved this problem in a stylish manner, where you need to add hover modifiers on a module's child:

```
.moduleName{
    &-item{
        &-figure{ ... }
    }



    &:hover{
        ...
        .moduleName-item{
            ...
        }
        .moduleName-item-figure{
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

I find the above example really ugly as the `moduleName` and `moduleName-item` is repetitive and not nice to look at.

I'm not fan of putting the modulename in a variable too.

Not quite sure what I'm looking for, it just bothers me.

Answer (score 0):

How about `&:hover &-child`? You wouldn't be able to wrap all the hover overrides together, but it would at least keep you from repeating the module name.

```
.moduleName{
    &-item{
        &-figure{ ... }
    }

        &:hover &-item{
            ...
        }

        &:hover &-item-figure{
            ...
        }
}
```

I have the overrides indented to show they have greater specificity, but you can see that syntactically they would normally be aligned with the `&-item{`.